# Magento Admin - Compare products on-screen or via export (using diff)

Tags: admin, magento-1

I've taken over the admin of an established magento site, however, I have little magento experience, so I'm hoping this is an easy task!

**Is there a way of comparing all of the settings for 2 products?** On-screen report or exporting product data to CSV (that I can diff) would be great.

By settings of a product I mean values from each of the left side tabs [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdpp3.jpg).

[image]

Currently we have to manually click on each tab to compare the values, which is very slow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export products csvs for both products and perform your comparison.

Go to `System->Import/Export ->Export` select **Entity Type** Products and under SKU field specify SKU of the first item and click export. Now repeat the process for the second item and bingo.

Comment: I don't have Import/Export under my System menu. We're using Magento ver 1.14.x

Comment: I take you're using Enterprise edition! If yes then there is Import/Export menu as described above and explained in Devdocs http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/store-operations/data-export.html. You may not have access to it (user privileges)!!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will get the required permissions, test out answer (which looks correct) and then mark as correct asap.

Comment: Works perfectly. I don't suppose there's a way of saving a list/template of which columns to export to CSV?

Comment: You can use Dataflow Profiles under Import/Export tab. Create a new profile  and add required fields under Field Mapping section :)